QGIS latest installer for Windows
We are testing installation of QGIS on Windows 10 x64 VM.
As per the download page
"The current version is QGIS 3.36.3 'Maidenhead' and was released on 17.05.2024.
The long-term repositories currently offer QGIS 3.34.7 'Prizren'."
but both these releases are not available to download for Windows.
Is this release not applicable for Windows?
If its applicable where can we get installer for both versions?

The latest release 3.36.3 seems to not be in there yet : all installer list, Though the 3.36.3 has only been out for a few days so it is probably coming

I can confirm that the OSGeo4W installer works fine for both the latest QGIS versions

Well, they fixed it, just needed to wait a bit.

Are you sure you're looking in the right place? I can find both installers at https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html , and am also on Windows.
As you can see I have the options to download both 3.34 and 3.36.

have you tried clicking it, the file isn't there

yes, you are correct. I alreay had QGIS installed, so didn't click on the links. alternatively you can use the osgeo4w installer, which can be downloaded. moreover, with osgeo4w you can install both versions, and see which one works better for you

I clicked the download link and it started downloading QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.36.3-1.msi

Also there in the full list https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/ and has been since 2024-May-21 01:56 so a bit of a lag, but reasonable.
